# SQLite: "IN" comparison question

Tags: android, sqlite

I wish to execute the following query on my application's
SQliteDatabase.

```
String sql = "Select col_1,row_id from Table1 where row_id IN(Select
row_id from Table2 where key = 'key')";
```

I am using the `rawQuery` function of the `SQLiteDataBase` class for the
same. The problem is when the inner query returns 0 objects the query
runs and returns 0 results. But when the inner query returns a Set, the
query is not executed.

Can we have nested queries like these in rawQuery? What is it that I
am missing here?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a join?

```
SELECT Table1.col_1, Table1.row_id FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.row_id = Table2.row_id WHERE key = 'key';
```

Comment: I am not very versed with databases so please excuse my ignorance. I have two questions:
1. Are JOINs better than nested queries in terms of space and memory?
2. Any idea why the above mentioned query doesn't work on Android? i tried it on the SQlite Database browser and it works.

Comment: Databases are usually optimized to run JOINs. Internally most query optimizers will transform your nested query into a join. 
Without any error message I can't tell why it doesn't work when the subquery returns a set. The syntax is correct!